# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect

Tags: php

I have a fresh installation of XAMPP and I used to get PHP notices to turn them off I enbabled:

```
Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

in the php.ini.

And now I have the problem that I get the error message, which you can read in the title of this question. Though, the same function would work when I would not have that one error_reporting enabled.

When restarting the Apache server, I also get the error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected '&' in .../php.ini on line 110.
```

Line 110 is the error_reporting I enabled which you can see above.

I am trying to make sense out of this but I seem to have troubles. Any ideas what is going on here?

By the way, php_mysql.dll and php_mysqli.dll are both enabled in the php.ini file.

Comment: Can you paste some more lines from your php.ini file around that line?

Comment: Can you post line 110 of your ini file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Isn't valid in the php.ini file. What you want is:

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Comment: +1. BTW, does anyone know if `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE` is valid in php.ini?

Comment: Here are the lines around line 110 as requested, by the way I did try the suggestion of Tom, the function itself does work, but I am still getting notices, it works as if there is no error reporting enabled at all.
`; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

; html_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production value: Off
`

Answer (score 0):

Well this may not be the most technical reply.

But what I did was , tool backup of all my tables, Uninstalled and reinstalled the WAMP server on my laptop and it worked. This surely works. It is also the most time consuming.

To this day I have not been able to figure out why my WAMP server stopped functioning. (only the MySQL part of it). The only thing I know is that Windows made some updates on the system (which I did not authorise) and the next time it started kaboom, it was no longer functioning.

After the reinstall , do the normal things - restart, go to IIS and stop the service, go to services and stop all MSSQL server services.